# Regex "match.Groups["T4"]" is not printing full content

Tags: c#, regex

Below Regex Match group giving truncated output for `T4`

```
var input = @": May 13 01:16:14.736 UTC: %XYZ-3-PQR: Hello R0 / 16, changed state";
        var regex = new Regex(@":\s+(?<Date>[^%]+)%(?<T1>[A-Za-z]+)-(?<T2>\d+)-(?<T3>[A-Za-z]+):\s+(?<T4>[\w]+)");
        var match = regex.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Date"]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["T1"]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["T2"]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["T3"]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["T4"]);
        }
```

Output,

`Date: May 13 01:16:14.736 UTC:
T1: XYZ
T2: 3
T3: PQR
T4: Hello`

`T4` output should be: **Hello R0 / 16, changed state**

Regex Validation is also good. Is there anything we need to change Regex expression?

Comment: What is the logic behind the `T4` match?  Do you want to just capture the remainder?

Comment: Yes, I want to capture full content

Comment: T4 matches `[\w]+`. A space is not matched by `\w` so T4 *cannot* be `Hello R0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you want to capture in `T4` the remainder of the line.  If so, then just use `.*`, i.e. capture the `T4` named group using this:

```
(?<T4>.*)
```

**Code:**

```
var input = @": May 13 01:16:14.736 UTC: %XYZ-3-PQR: Hello R0 / 16, changed state";
var regex = new Regex(@":\s+(?<Date>[^%]+)%(?<T1>[A-Za-z]+)-(?<T2>\d+)-(?<T3>[A-Za-z]+):\s+(?<T4>.*)");
var match = regex.Match(input);
```

Here is the output from your print statements with the above slight change to your regex:

```
May 13 01:16:14.736 UTC: 
XYZ
3
PQR
Hello R0 / 16, changed state
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

The shorthand character class \w doesn't match spaces (or slashes, or commas) so the capture is stopping at the first space. Add a space (and slash, comma and any other non word characters you're expecting) to the character class e.g. `[\w /,]`